# Facebook signup / linking in django rest with custom manual login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, facebook-login

What is the end-to-end architecture to implement Facebook signup/linking in Django rest when using custom manual login which has mobile number as the primary key ? Also what is the best and most efficient way to do this. ?

Comment: You can use [social-auth-app-django](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html) for facebook login/signup part. Check [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)

Comment: Thanks @fxgx for reverting. I have referred this tutorial earlier(and its pretty good also) but it just shows how to implement it when there is only Facebook login. However I want something more robust than this, which helps me to sync between the manually signed-up users (with phone no.) and the users who opt to sign up with Facebook (which may have the same phone number as the one signed up manually). So wanted to know how to accomplish this. ?